# undefined method `ceo_name=' for #<Chiefexecutiveofficer id: nil>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

Say "i want to save my data in database but one error is occur in both controller.

This is my Controller Code.....

```
class ChiefexecutiveofficerController < ApplicationController
def new

end
def index
    @chiefexecutiveofficer = Chiefexecutiveofficer.all
end
def create

    @chiefexecutiveofficer = Chiefexecutiveofficer.new()
    @chiefexecutiveofficer.ceo_name = params[:chiefexecutiveofficer][:ceo_name]
    @chiefexecutiveofficer.ceo_pin = params[:chiefexecutiveofficer][:ceo_pin]
    @chiefexecutiveofficer.ceo_address = params[:chiefexecutiveofficer][:ceo_address]
    @chiefexecutiveofficer.ceo_salary = params[:chiefexecutiveofficer][:ceo_salary]



    if @chiefexecutiveofficer.save
         flash[:notice]= " Your CEO Record Is Successfully Created"
            redirect_to  welcome_index_path
    else

        flash[:notice]= " Your CEO record Is Not Created"
            redirect_to  welcome_index_path
    end 
end



private

def my_params
    params.require(:chiefexecutiveofficer).permit(:ceo_name,:ceo_name,:ceo_address,:ceo_salary)

end

end
```

Comment: Please show the table and class definition of `Chiefexecutiveofficer`. It sounds like there is no attribute `ceo_name` on that class. Maybe it's just `name`?

Comment: That's a very strange class name.

Comment: What does the error say?